# How to train LSTM with single label per "batch"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to train stateful LSTM model for time-series prediction.
Initially I assumed that I should write :

```
    for batch in range(len(features) - window_size):

        # get arrays for the batch
        fb = features[batch:batch+window_size,:]
        lb = labels[batch:batch+window_size,:]

        #reshape
        fb = fb.reshape(1, fb.shape[0], fb.shape[1])
        lb = lb.reshape(1, lb.shape[0], lb.shape[1])

        # train        
        model.train_on_batch(fb, lb) # .fit(fb, lb, epochs=1, batch_size=window_size)
```

the above is supposed to take a fixed size window of say 100 out of 10000 samples and train for each moving by one at each iteration (0..99, 1..100, 2..101 etc). In this case x and y has same length of 100.

Here the window and the batch are the same. But in practical sense, one window/batch has one label.

Consider data representing moving cat video and a window to be a snapshot/picture and it can be classified with one label only not 100 labels. imagine it is picture of a cat. and having 100 labels means that each row must be labelled somehow, but practically it makes no sense. One snapshot can be labelled for example as distance the cat moved. So window 1 label is 0, window 2 - 1mm etc..

Am i misunderstanding batch definition in the describing my model ?

**What would be correct input/output shapes / batch size in this case?**

EDIT: video is brought in as a mean to explain myself. in reality dataset is number of days, where each day is 10000 measures (samples in normal world) with 7 inputs/features and 8 one-hot labels. Currently input shape for train_on_batch is (1, 100, 32) [32 is LSTM neurons number].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video classification is generally done using Convolutional Networks with 3D convolutional kernels. As an example, look at [this paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/42455.pdf) by Google and Standford researcher.

In your case, you are using a LSTM and it doesn't make sense to label every single frame of your windows. What you could do is to have only one output and compare it to your label (many-to-one acrchitecture). In other words, even though your LSTM cell produces output at every single step, you only consider the output at the final step to compute your loss.

```
for epoch in n_epoch: # number of batches to show to your LSTM
    # batch_features = numFrames x batchSize x numChannel x Width x Height
    # batch_labels   = batchSize x 1
    batch_features, batch_labels = getBatch() 

    # initialize cell state
    h = zeros()
    for frame in numFrames:
        # here the main loop of the LSTM. out will be constantly overwritten
        h, out = LSTM(h, batch_features[frame])

    # use only the final output to compute the loss
    loss = crossEntropywithLogits(out, batch_labels)
```

Comment: thank you. video meant to help the explanation (see edit). I am going to try your suggestion however the model currently run for 1hr for each day of data on K80 GPU and I have hundreds of days. I was hoping to cut these times by not running each label